# YouTube Download not available

Tags: 7.0-nougat, youtube, offline

I was on vacation in Asia a couple of weeks ago with my old cell phone. I discovered the YouTube offline feature and loved it!

Now, back home, i tried to use it with my newer cell and discovered that there is no download/offline button in my YouTube app.

Why is that? Is it possible that this feature installed abroad, but was actually not available in my home country? 
Most important: How can I watch YouTube videos offline?

[image]

Comment: No, check the screenshot taken from the “impressions“ section of Google play store, just added.

Comment: Version is noted by tag: 7.0

Comment: There is a way to download videos from YouTube even if you don't have the option in the app. Go to savefrom.net paste the YouTube link, and download. Not as smooth as the option in the app though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am from India where we have this feature and didn't know that it is **not** universally available

From [YouTube help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6141269?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

You can download only in these countries

> - Algeria
> - Egypt
> - Ghana
> - India
> - Indonesia
> - Jordan
> - Kenya
> - Libya
> - Malaysia
> - Nigeria
> - Pakistan
> - Philippines
> - South Africa
> - Thailand
> - Vietnam
> - Yemen

Reasons not stated but [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/3bvqk1/why_is_youtube_offline_available_only_for_some) there is an explanation given two years ago by a user who seems to be from YouTube

Alternate option is to use YouTube Red

Comment: Wow, thank you, that clears why i didn't even find the topic in local communities... Your post from YouTube help seems to be visible in the listed companies only, as well.

Comment: Welcome . Then it's good the list of countries is mentioned (was about to just post the link only)

Comment: I travel between India and UAE several times a year. This offline feature will appear and disappear. +1